# Offer Unique Coupon Code For Foursquare Checkin?

Tags: web-services, foursquare

I'm trying to run a promotion for foursquare venue's so when a person check's into their location they are given a unique code to redeem on the venue's website when checking out in their online store. Is this possible? I see all over you can give out coupons but no where can I find in the API you can run a service to generate a code. I have the service created with PHP already to give codes according to the users IP.

Anyone know a solution to achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no service built into the API to generate/display a unique code. Generally people with this use case give a URL in the unlock copy for the user to click on which takes them to a site which gives them a code / unique QR code / etc.